# Why does In-App update fail with resultCode 0?

Tags: android, in-app-update

When testing [In-App Updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates), the update downloads but fails to install with a resultCode of 0 (RESULT_CANCELED) in `onActivityResult`.

In addition, the update version is not the most recent version updated to the track (using internal track).  I Have these versions released on internal track:
1
2
3

When make a build with versionCode 1, it attempts to update to 2, but fails.
When make a build with versionCode 2, it says the app is up to date.

I have tried uploading new builds, with the same error.  I have waited 2 days and tested again with same results.

The app is published with app bundles.

Also App is reported as up to date when I installed the playstore version 3 (internal track) and then publish a version 4.  The playstore shows the update button, but in-app updates does not report an update available.

Comment: Sorry, I've only ever had an `onActivityResult` of `RESULT_OK` or `RESULT_CANCELED`. My app doesn't use app bundles. When I tested, I changed my `versionCode` in Android Studio to be an earlier version than what was available on the play store, and then I started the app and saw that an update was available.

I've also been able to install from my private alpha track using in-app updates.

Comment: resultCode of 1 is first user-defined activity result, so, not sure where that would be coming from.  I trap for RESULT_OK, RESULT_CANCELED and ELSE. If OK, I issue a .completeUpdate and in all cases finish with a .unregisterListener.  In the onResume method, I issue a .checkForStalledUpdate where I add a appUpdateInfoTask.addOnFailureListener to listen for an onFailure exception for stalled updates. I add a appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener which is where you check to see if there is an update available and whether an update is allowed.  Check for all possible results.

Comment: @MichaelDougan it is a resultCode 0.  I've updated the questions with the correct code.

Comment: Unfortunately no resolution to this. We ended up handling this with a custom update dialog that sends user to the playstore when this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I tested my Auto-Update using an Internal Test Track, and what I did was open the Google Play App Store on the AVD emulator I was testing on, open to my App's Page.  I downloaded the first test build from the internal test track onto the emulator through the Google Play App on the emulator to set up the test the first time.  Then, whenever I uploaded another build to the internal test track, I would refresh the app page in the Google Play App on the emulator until I saw the new build number was available - which was pretty soon after I uploaded it, then, I ran my tests.  So, it shouldn't take days.  The App Store on the device should recognize if you are running a build from the internal test track if you've done this, and it should show the new internal test track build on the App Store app on the AVD almost immediately.

Though, it's pretty easy to get the App Store confused, and it might be checking your published app version instead of your internal test track version if you go back and forth with different versions on the device you are testing on.

I also found that the FLEXIBLE update was more glitchy than the IMMEDIATE update, and so, have stuck with that for production.

Comment: These steps are what I have been doing.  I see the update in the playstore, but in-app update says the app is up to date.  This happens when I installed from the app store (internal track) and still in the internal track.  not track jumping here.  It appears to be checking if the versionCode is less than an older update that I've published.  If I make a build with versionCode below that particular version it will try to update, but fail.

Comment: I don't think you can make a build with a lower version code to test. There is something about the build, maybe because it is signed with a different keystore, that confuses it. I've always left the version installed on the AVD or test device which was the last one downloaded through the Google Play App Store on that device, then, I've uploaded a new build with an incremented version number, then run the old version that was downloaded through Google Play, not a fresh build with a lower number to test.  I did enough tests to be up into the 90's build number before I was finished!

Comment: I've read other posts of people making builds with a lower versionCode and installing via adb for testing.  I agree signing could be an issue with app signing b/c I don't have the signing key.  That is the only time it triggered an update -although it was for the wrong version and it failed.  Installing from app store and publishing new version simply doesn't trigger an update, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: I had to put log messages everywhere, because you can't set breakpoints and step through the code as you would like to do.  I logged every method I entered, so I could see when I hit the onSuccess and onFail listeners, and log every result code returned to see if an update was available, or not, or available, but not allowed.  See when state changes and and see what the install state is when called. I hit a fair number of cases of 'stalled' updates.  When I would get one, I'd have to delete the app off the device and re-download, then, upload another new build to resume testing.

Comment: I have toasts everywhere too.  It successfully checks for update and says there is not an update available - unless I install a version with adb & a low versionCode.  Playstore sees the update and shows the 'update' button.  Tried multiple devices with same result.